# SSS_INVALID_SRCH_COLUMN_JOIN on leadsource.title column in CUSTOMER search

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

Can anyone tell me why the script below fails in the NetSuite Script Debugger on API Version 2.0? As far as I can tell, the search and the join should be valid based on [supported search joins for the `customer` record type](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_2/script/record/customer.html) and [available fields on the `campaign` record type](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_2/script/record/campaign.html).

```js
require(['N/search'],
  function(search) {

    // `leadsource` is listed as a search join for `customer`.
    // See https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_2/script/record/customer.html
    //
    // `title` is listed as a field for `campaign`.
    // See https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_2/script/record/campaign.html
    search.create({
      type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
      title: 'Customers',
      columns: [
        'leadsource',
        'leadsource.title',
        'companyname',
        'internalid'
      ]
    }).run().each(function(customerResult) {
      // ...
    });
  }
);
```

Below is the error I'm getting.

```json
{
  "type": "error.SuiteScriptError",
  "name": "SSS_INVALID_SRCH_COLUMN_JOIN",
  "message": "An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column join ID, or is not in proper syntax: title.",
  "stack": [
    "each(N/search/searchObject.js)",
    "<anonymous>(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:18)",
    "<anonymous>(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:1)"
  ],
  "cause": {
    "type": "internal error",
    "code": "SSS_INVALID_SRCH_COLUMN_JOIN",
    "details": "An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column join ID, or is not in proper syntax: title.",
    "userEvent": null,
    "stackTrace": [
      "each(N/search/searchObject.js)",
      "<anonymous>(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:18)",
      "<anonymous>(adhoc$-1$debugger.user:1)"
    ],
    "notifyOff": false
  },
  "id": "",
  "notifyOff": false,
  "userFacing": false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `'leadsource.title'` to a javascript object `{ join: 'leadsource', name: 'title' }`

```js
search.create({
  type: search.Type.CUSTOMER,
  title: 'Customers',
  columns: [
    'leadsource',
    { join: 'leadsource', name: 'title' },
    'companyname',
    'internalid'
  ]
})
```

Or you can also try to reverse the string to `'title.leadsource'` as according to the error it's trying to create a join on the `title` field, while it should be on the `leadsource` field.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately I tried [using the JavaScript object](https://imgur.com/a/MTXFXko) but got the exact same error. Switching the order from `leadsource.title` to `title.leadsource` just changed the error message to complaining about "leadsource" instead of "title". What's confusing is [NetSuite docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4345767216.html) show a direct example of using dot notation to return parent fields in the search.

Comment: I've just tested in our environment, both your setup, with the dot-notation, and mine, with the javascript object, do work for me.